# how do i push my war file to nexus repository automatically updating version id using jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins setup with Maven as a build tool. Java project is pulled from SVN and it is built using Maven (all inside Jenkins). Once the project is built I get project.war package file which I need to be uploaded to Nexus Repository automatically using build setup Nexus Repository Manager publisher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Jenkins Job you can set in the build section following maven goal:

```
deploy -Drevision=$BUILD_NUMBER
```

In your Maven Project's POM you define `<version>1.0.${revision}</version>` e.g. to have version starting with 1.0.X. X means the current build number of your Jenkins build that gets set via the revision variable.

Comment: in build section there is no option named deploy , i am using Nexus Repository Manager Publosher plugin

Comment: I meant the maven goal

Comment: where i have to declare that $BUID_NUMBER variable

Comment: Its automatically injected Fron Jenkins.